# python multiple input select

Tags: python

I have a html form with multiple input select. How I can select all items, using python grab?

```
<select name="id_project[]" multiple="">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select it manually like a grab.submit(extra_post={"id_project[]":"1,2,3"}). Also see the issue https://bitbucket.org/lorien/grab/issue/40/multipleselectoptions-form_fields